# When using F5VPN traffic doesn't go through the vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

At work, in order to access some private resources, I have to use F5 VPN
if I use it on Windows it works just fine, but if I switch (dual-boot) to Ubuntu it doesn't work anymore.
The VPN says that I am connected, but I noticed that I can access some resources that shouldn't be accessible while using the VPN. And, since the VPN measures the traffic, I tried to do a speedtest and noticed that the measured traffic doesn't even increase by 1B.

So I tried searching on the internet how to redirect all the traffic through the VPN and found this command: `sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 <vpn_interface>`, but nothing changed.